# Inquitetudes sobre límite de ediciones diario permitidos a un usuario

Tags: soporte, ediciones

Estaba editando mis respuestas en Stack Overflow en español y me ha aparecido la siguiente imagen:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Demasiadas ediciones
>
> Hoy ya editaste 10 de tus propias publicaciones (sin contar las publicaciones muy recientes). No se permiten más ediciones hasta mañana.
>
> Si necesitas asistencia, comunícate con un moderador.

Soy un usuario relativamente nuevo (menos de 6 meses). Tengo varias inquietudes e ideas sobre esto:

1. **¿Por qué existe una limitación en las ediciones?**

Son mis respuestas las que estoy editando y mis preguntas. Deduzco que el límite es para evitar cambios innecesarios a las publicaciones, sin embargo, no veo por qué no pueda realizar ediciones ilimitadas a mis publicaciones y es por ello que realizo esta pregunta.

2. **¿Por qué la limitación es global?**

No debería ser individual tomando esta palabra en el sentido de que si edito 10 veces la misma respuesta o pregunta (puede que la validación se reduzca a 5 veces siendo individual) debería aparecer el mensaje que mostré en la imagen. Como está actualmente, es decir, global sólo permite realizar 10 ediciones en el total de mis preguntas y respuestas y por ejemplo yo pretendía mejorar mis 40 respuestas (poco más de 40) que tengo hoy.

3. **¿Podré editar publicaciones nuevas?**

Sé que parte del mensaje enuncia:

> Hoy ya editaste 10 de tus propias publicaciones (sin contar las publicaciones muy recientes)

Pero es mejor cerciorarme ya que no existe pregunta tonta sino tonto que no pregunta... ¿Si hago publicaciones nuevas (como esta pregunta por ejemplo) y la edito podría hacerlo, o también debo esperar a mañana?

Lo mismo va para mis respuestas nuevas. Si hoy doy una respuesta nueva, ¿podría editarla de ser necesario? Porque me preocupa equivocarme o no explicarme bien en una respuesta (por tanto deba corregirla)  y al intentar editarla me salga esta restricción.

4. **¿Se podría implementar un Captcha?**

¿En vez de limitar las ediciones es factible que se cambie esto por un captcha? En vista que no conozco el propósito de la limitación de edición me es difícil estimar si un captcha podría sustituir la limitación mientras cumple el mismo objetivo.

5. Como dije antes soy un usuario nuevo, **¿cómo hago para contactar a un moderador como me expresa el mensaje de restricción?**

Comment: Antes de seguir editando, te recomendaría ver por qué fueron rechazadas 4 de tus últimas 5 sugerencias de edición. Podés ver el listado y los motivos en https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/70868/huskie?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Me pregunto si en verdad son necesarias esas ediciones, si son pregunta/respuestas que se realizaron con anterioridad, ¿se agrega más información?, ¿Se corrige ortografía?.

Comment: Dado el comentario de Mariano, veo que sigues un patrón en la edición de preguntas/respuestas: poner en negritas o resaltar algunas palabras que no aportan a entender o mejorar la pregunta o respuesta, incluso en esta pregunta pasó lo mismo. Algunas de ellas son ediciones aceptadas y como ejemplo las últimas 4, rechazadas.

Comment: @Jorgesys En algunas he corregido ortografía pero en otras solo mejoraba la presentación de las respuestas para que fuese mas agradable leerlas. Lamento el inconveniente

Comment: @Mariano Como dije antes soy nuevo en el sitio. Me iré adaptando conforme pase el tiempo. No tenia conocimiento que podía ver si mis ediciones fueron o no rechazadas. Gracias Mariano.

Comment: @Flxtr Realmente estaba editando para resaltar palabras clave. Si estoy leyendo algo por internet y necesito buscar la solución rapidamente o sencillamente no dispongo del tiempo suficiente para ahondar en un tema busco en las palabras resaltadas y me hago una idea del tema en general (skimming, scanning). Trato de facilitar esta misma técnica en mis respuestas para ahorrar tiempo a otros usuarios que la leen. Esa era mi intención, lamento si no es la mejor (no lo sabía). Dejaré de hacerlo. Gracias por la aclaratoria. Un Saludo.

Comment: @Huskie más vale! Tengo más que claro que estás ayudando a moderar el sitio, y ojalá más usuarios hicieran lo mismo que estás haciendo, o más aún acercarse a Meta con preguntas como hiciste. Todos fuimos nuevos y todos seguimos contrastando opiniones en Meta.. Los comentarios fueron en base a tu pregunta, intentando ayudarte sobre tu inquietud.. Desde ya, espero que sigas intentando mejorar las preguntas, tomando el feedback de acá, y buscando que se aumente la calidad del contenido del sitio.. En caso de que no sepas cómo proceder con algo, seguí preguntando acá (o informalmente en el [chat])

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano! Agradecido nuevamente por la aclaratoría y por el apoyo brindado! Un Saludo.

Comment: @Huskie no tienes que lamentar, al contrario que bueno que tratas de mejorar la información, te sugiero revises las razones por las cuales la comunidad rechazo los cambios que trataste de realizar, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Ok. Muchas gracias por el apoyo y estaré atento de hacer lo necesario para que no se rechacen las ediciones. Gracias Jorgesys. Un Saludo!

Comment: @Huskie recordemos que el uso de negritas debería ser solamente cuando el usuario quiere poner énfasis en una parte de la pregunta. No son para señalar términos como PHP, JavaScript, etc. que no deberían ir en negritas (me refiero a https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/139435/revisions)

Comment: @Mariano Ok. Sólo realizaré correcciones de sintaxis y errores ortográficos

Comment: @Mariano Si quiero expresar una idea/sugerencia sobre una nueva funcionalidad para stackoverflow. La pregunta va aquí en META?

Comment: Ok. Gracias nuevamente @Mariano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) ¿Por qué existe una limitación en las ediciones?

Esto se debe a una protección al sistema mismo ya que se puede interpretar a que estás jugando con él editando tus propias publicaciones, además se evita tráfico innecesario y ediciones periódicas. Lo mismo ocurre al eliminar tus respuestas, Tendras un número limitado de eliminaciones ya que se puede interpretar como vandalismo.

> 2) ¿Por qué la limitación es "global"?

Por la misma razón del punto 1. Sin importar que edites la misma respuesta o cada una de las 40 que tienes el resultado sería el mismo, se puede mal interpretar o en su caso se toma como vandalizar. Ahora yo te pregunto, **¿cuál es el objetivo de editar tus 40 preguntas?**

> 3) ¿Podré editar publicaciones nuevas?

Lamentablemente no tengo la respuesta a esta pregunta. Pero puedes intentar hacer el ejercicio por ti mismo. Responde alguna pregunta e intenta editarla una vez que han transcurrido 5 minutos. Con esto sabrás el resultado.

> 4) ¿Se podría implementar un Captcha?

De igual manera que el punto 3, no tengo la respuesta. Pero esto va mucho más allá de una pequeña implementación de un componente teniendo como referencia los miles de usuarios que se tienen en toda la red de Stack Exchange, número de peticiones de validación de Captcha, costos de implementación etc. Podrías hacer la propuesta aquí en el sitio Meta para saber exactamente si es posible.

> 5) Como dije antes soy un usuario nuevo, como hago para contactar a un moderador como me expresa el mensaje de restricción?

Si tienes más dudas al respecto sugiero que revises la página [¿Quiénes son los moderadores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) y al ver esta publicación pueden hacerles mención en los comentarios o ellos se pondrán en contacto contigo en caso que así lo requieras.

Comment: Hay CAPTCHA en SE. El tema es que no se dispara en estos casos, sino en otros. Usan el reCAPTCHA de Google.

Comment: Si @Mariano me he fijado que pasa cuando tienes mucho tiempo la sesión abierta etc. En ciertos casos he visto que pide el captcha